# As3 - How to clear an array efficiently?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I've been looking to clear an array in ActionScript 3.

Some method suggest : `array = [];` (Memory leak?)

Other would say : `array.splice(0);`

If you have any other, please share.
Which one is the more efficient?

Thank you.

Comment: Memory leak ? Garbage collection!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`array.length = 0` or `array.splice()` seems to work best for overall performance.

`array.splice(0);` will perform faster than `array.splice(array.length - 1, 1);`

Comment: I know this is an old topic but how about setting an array to null?

Comment: Actually `array = null;` gets rid of the Array itself instead of just cleaning it. Its basically the same that happens when you `array = [];`, the previous array reference is lost and will probably be garbage collected (which might not be the wanted outcome).

Comment: Why do not `array = new Array()`?

Answer (score 6):

For array with 100 elements (benchmarks in ms, the lower the less time needed):

```
// best performance (benchmark: 1157)
array.length = 0;
// lower performance (benchmark: 1554)
array = [];
// even lower performance (benchmark: 3592)
array.splice(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

I wonder, why you want to clear the Array in that manner? clearing all references to that very array will make it available for garbage collection. `array = []` will do so, if `array` is the only reference to the `array`. if it isn't then you maybe shouldn't be emtpying it (?)

also, please note that`Arrays accept Strings as keys. both splice and lenght operate solely on integer keys, so they will have no effect on String keys.

btw.: `array.splice(array.length - 1, 1);` is equivalent to `array.pop();`

Comment: I do want to make it avaible to garbage collection, I want to empty it.

Comment: Pretty sure arrays in AS3 don't accept strings as keys.  Objects do, but not Arrays.

Comment: @Omnomlets: you're wrong. next time, try verifying your statements.

Comment: You're right.  I suppose that's because Array extends Object in the first place.  Thanks!  You learn something every day.

Answer (score 2):

There is a key difference between array.pop() and array.splice(array.length - 1, 1) which is that pop will return the value of the element.  This is great for handy one liners when clearing out an array like:

```
while(myArray.length > 0){
     view.removeChild(myArray.pop());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array.splice(0,array.length);
```

this has always worked pretty well for me but I haven't had a chance to run it through the profiler yet